# ComboBox does not update selected item

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

The JavaFx ComboBox does not update its selected item when the underlying object changes. To give a simple example:

```
StringProperty item1 = new SimpleStringProperty("Item-1");
StringProperty item2 = new SimpleStringProperty("Item-2");
StringProperty item3 = new SimpleStringProperty("Item-3");

ObservableList<StringProperty> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(item1, item2, item3);

ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
comboBox.setItems(items);
comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(item1);

StackPane root = new StackPane();
root.getChildren().add(comboBox);
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();

Timeline timeline1 = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
Duration.millis(1000), ae -> {
                item1.set("Changing the string");
}));
timeline1.play();
```

In want the ComboBox to reflect the changes I made to `item1`. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Do you really need the items in the list to be `StringProperty`s, instead of just `String`s? If so, presumably you have a cell factory and button cell set on the combo box... can you post that code too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have already defined a cell factory and button cell on the combo box, so that you get the elements in the list displayed nicely, if you implement that to bind the cell's text property to the appropriate property it will work:

```
public static class StringPropertyCell extends ListCell<StringProperty> {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(StringProperty item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        textProperty().unbind();
        if (item != null && ! empty) {
            textProperty().bind(item);
        }
    }

}
```

and then, obviously,

```
ComboBox<StringProperty> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
comboBox.setItems(items);
comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(item1);

comboBox.setCellFactory(lv -> new StringPropertyCell());
comboBox.setButtonCell(new StringPropertyCell());
```

Otherwise, you need to construct the underlying list with an [extractor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-):

```
ObservableList<StringProperty> items = 
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(e -> new Observable[] {e});
items.addAll(item1, item2, item3);
```

Also note you can actually achieve the desired effect (at least in the example code you posted) using just a list of plain `String`s instead of a list of `StringProperty`s:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ComboBoxTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Item-1", "Item-2", "Item-3");

        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        comboBox.setItems(items);
        comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(comboBox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Timeline timeline1 = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
        Duration.millis(1000), ae -> {
            items.set(0, "Changing the string");
        }));
        timeline1.play();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(comboBox), 300, 100));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```